# How to persist data using Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I have a Apollo client and server with a React app in which users can log in. This is the Apollo server mutation for the login:

```
  loginUser: async (root, args) => {
    const theUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {email: String(args.email)},
    });
    if (!theUser) throw new Error('Unable to Login');
    const isMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(args.password, theUser.password);
    if (!isMatch) throw new Error('Unable to Login');
    return {token: jwt.sign(theUser, 'supersecret'), currentUser: theUser};
  },
```

This returns a JWT and the user that's logging in.

In my React app I have a login component:

```
// Login.tsx

  const [loginUserRes] = useMutation(resolvers.mutations.LoginUser);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {data} = await loginUserRes({variables: {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password,
    }});
    if (data) {
      currentUserVar({
        email: data.loginUser.currentUser.email,
        id: data.loginUser.currentUser.id,
        loggedIn: true,
      });
      window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginUser.token);
    }
  };
```

This function passes the form data to the `LoginUser` mutation which returns data if authentication is successful. Then I have a reactive variable called `currentUserVar` I store the email and id of the user in there so I can use it throughout the application. Finally I store the JWT in a LocalStorage so I can send it for authorization:

```
// index.tsx

const authLink = setContext((_, {headers}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Everything is working, except for the fact that if a user refreshes the user data is gone and they have to log in again, which is of course quite annoying.

So I was hoping to get some advice on how to persist the data, perhaps using Apollo? I suppose I could add a checkbox with a `remember me` function that stores the email and id in the LocalStorage and when the app initiates check if there's user data in the LocalStorage and than use that, but I was wondering if there's a better/other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the login problem , you have set the headers on your every single request , but did you pass a fuction to the ApolloServer constructor that checks the headers from every single request ? Something like this:

```
const server=new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context:async({req})=>{
     const me=getMe(req)
     return {
      models,
      me,
      process.env.SECRET
    }
  }
})


const getMe = async req => {
  const token = req.headers['x-token'];
 
  if (token) {
    try {
      return await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new AuthenticationError(
        'Your session expired. Sign in again.',
      );
    }
  }
};
```

As for the data persistence part of the question , you have to use `setItem` to persist the token in the locatStorage.